# Should graphs and charts be reversed for RTL-reading audiences?

Tags: data-visualisation

I don't recall ever seeing any examples of right-to-left-reading charts and graphs, so I'm guessing the answer is no; however, I wanted to ask here to see if anyone has information to the contrary: for readers of right-to-left languages, are charts and graphs reversed, reading from right to left also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no concrete rule**. But here are some points to consider:

- Most icons and such are positioned to the right and the text to the left on RTL websites.
- Standardized graphs such as timelines and math plots stay the same. Sometimes the labels are on the right instead of the left side.
- Readers are generally comfortable reading charts in a left-to-right way.

The screen show below is [from Al Jazeera's website](http://www.aljazeera.net/news/arabic/2016/2/11/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86-%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AD-%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B0%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%85%D9%87). As seen, the icons are on the right, but the icons in the diagram are on the left.

[image]

[Another Al Jazeera page](http://www.aljazeera.net/specialfiles/pages/7165406c-2ce7-4c5b-81a1-19ec7bdd95da) uses a bar charts with labels on the right axis:

[image]

Comment: For more general information on designing for right to left languages, [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/43161/23061) might be useful